# downloading using wget for multiple files, with renaming of files

Tags: wget

I am aware that you can download from multiple url using:

```
wget "url1" "url2" "url3"
```

Renaming the output file can be done via:

```
wget "url1" -O "new_name1"
```

But when I tried

```
wget "url1" "url2" "url3" -O "name1" "name2" "name3"
```

all the files are using name1.

what is the proper way to do so in a single command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes something like this, You can add a file name next to each URL in the file then do:

```
while IFS= read -r url fileName;do
    wget -O "$fileName" "$url"
done < list
```

where it is assumed you have added a (unique) file name after each URL in the file (separated by a space).

The `-O` option allows you to specify the destination file name. But if you're downloading multiple files at once, wget will save all of their content to the file you specify via `-O`. Note that in either case, the file will be truncated if it already exists. See the man page for more info.

You can exploit this option by telling wget to download the links one-by-one:

```
while IFS= read -r url;do
    fileName="blah" # Add a rule to define a new name for each file here
    wget -O "$fileName" "$url"
done < list
```

hope it useful.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have used curl for mine use and hence your purpose can also be satisfied with that,

```
curl -O -o name1 url1 -o name2 url2 url3
```

`-O` for downloading multiple files in 1 command

`-o` for providing filename for output

Here, first two url's. I.e. url1 and url2 will be downloaded and renamed to name1, name2 respectively and for url3 it will only be downloaded.